# How to include Bootstrap in an iFrame

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, head

I'm currently working on a project which requires me to use Bootstrap within an iFrame. I tried including it in the head of the document, but it's not being applied to the iFrame. I've been trying to insert the Bootstrap link into the head of the iFrame, but I can't target it. I even tried including it twice (in the containing document and in the head of the iFrame) and it's not being applied. Can anyone suggest a good way to do this?

Here's what I have so far:
index.html

```
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <iframe id="iframe" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

            <head>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            </head>

           </iframe>
      </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would u add CDN to body tag ? This is how iframe with bootstrap is done.

```html
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="row">
        <iframe id="iframe" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></iframe>
    </div>
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
   </html>
```